# TYPO3 SURF - Deploy non TYPO3 project

Tags: php, deployment, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, typo3-surf

I try to deploy a non TYPO3 project with TYPO3 SURF by following the offical documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/surf/2.0/en-us/GettingStarted/Index.html

I get the following errors under the task "SymlinkConfigurationTask":

```
bash: line 0: cd: /var/www/surf-test/releases/20190628085212/Configuration: No such file or directory
Got exception "Command returned non-zero return code: 1" rolling back.


In Task.php line 79:

  The required option "directories" is missing.
```

The task also creates a symlink to a folder that doesn't exist.

Here is my deployment script:

```
<?php
$node = new \TYPO3\Surf\Domain\Model\Node('T3 VM');
$node->setHostname('my-secret-host.com');
$node->setOption('password', 'secret');

$application = new \TYPO3\Surf\Application\Neos\Flow();
$application->setVersion('4.0');
$application->setDeploymentPath('/var/www/surf-test');
$application->setOption('repositoryUrl', 'git@my-secret-repo.git');
$application->addNode($node);

$deployment->addApplication($application);
```

Any help?

Comment: Why don't you use a completely framework agnostic deployment library, like [Deployer](https://deployer.org/), instead? That library also have a number of "recipes" for deploying many different type of applications.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you, that may be an alternative solution for a later time, but I want at the moment absolutely test the surf depoloyment tool.